# Click Again action for LinkButton in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a LinkButton. When a user clicks on it, a panel becomes visible.

How can I set it so if the LinkButton is clicked again this panel will become invisible?

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Panel2.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel2.Visible = !Panel2.Visible;
}
```